# C++ compiler gives unitialized variable warnings when declared in if-else statements

Tags: c++, compilation, compiler-warnings

I'm sure there's an easy explanation for this, but I have some code like this:

```
  RoutingTablePoolEntry rtpe;
  RoutingTablePoolEntry* rtpePtr;

  if (rtpeItr == m_rtpool.end()) {
    RoutingTableEntry* routeEntryPtr = m_nlsr.getRoutingTable()
      .findRoutingTableEntry(destRouter);

    if (routeEntryPtr == nullptr) {
      RoutingTablePoolEntry rtpe(destRouter);
    }
    else {
      RoutingTablePoolEntry rtpe(*routeEntryPtr);
    }

    RoutingTablePoolEntry* rtpePtr = addRtpeToPool(rtpe);
  }
  else {
    RoutingTablePoolEntry* rtpePtr = &(rtpeItr->second);
  }
  doSomeStuffWithRtpe()
```

EDIT: Here is some real code. Is the error still variable scope? I realize in the example it was, but is that still the problem here? I tried conditional initialization of the form:
`RoutingTablePoolEntry rtpe(routeEntryPtr == nullptr? ... : ...);` but that didn't seem to cooperate too much either.

EDIT #2: I'm an idiot, excuse me. The reason is abundantly clear and I just wasn't seeing it.

`rtpe = RoutingTablePoolEntry(destRouter)` and
`rtpePtr = &(rtpeItr->second)`
in the slim chance anyone makes this gaff, too.

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Note that `doThing` won't see neither of `object` declared in your code because they are out of scope.

Answer (score 5):

Each object declared in the statements following the if and else has the scope of these statements. After the if-else statement the object is not visible and alive.

Answer (score 1):

your variables are local to the if-statement. Probably you have a previous declaration of object, which is not initialized because is not used. In this situation, you get a warning, without any previous declaration of this object, you get an error.